# Confirming the solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

is this solution 'legal'?

Also fundamentally can ODE's have more that one solution.

The text book [solution](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781111427412-advanced-engineering-mathematics-7th-edition/30/problems/7/#).

[image]

Comment: So then there can exist multiple solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u'=-3x/u$ looks good to me. They used another substitution in the book to show how to deal with homogeneous DE. You should have $u=\pm \sqrt {C-3x^2}$ and the last step you forgot to divide by 2
$$x-2y= \pm \sqrt {C-3x^2} $$
Take the square on both sides:
$$x^2-4xy+4y^2= {C-3x^2}$$
Finally, you get the same answer as the book
$$x^2-xy+y^2= {K}$$

Comment: So then there can exist multiple solutions?

Comment: did you square it to check if it agrees with the book solution @Clintus

Comment: @Clintus it gives the same answer as the book

Answer (score 2):

$$y'=\frac{2x-y}{x-2y} \implies (y-2x)dx+(x-2y)dy=0=Mdx+Ndy~~~~(1)$$
As $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=1= \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$, it is an exact ODE, so its solution is
$$\int(y-2x) dx ~\text{(treat $y$ as constant)}+ \int (-2y ) dy =C$$
$$\implies xy-x^2-y^2=C$$

It(1) can also be seen as Homogeneous ODE and it can be solved using $y=vx$.